# How to set background in facebook login page like this?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

How to set background in facebook login page like this ?

I try to do, but not work.

In developer facebook, i set every image success. But my site not have background like digipoint

How can i do that ?

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/dd3/7mzpsg.png

Answer (score 0):

Upload app screenshots and logos in 'app details' section of developer dashboard.

To fill app details go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR-APPID/app-details/